Asymptotic significance level of the bootstrap Anderson-Darling test
Suppose we wish to test whether a given distribution $F$ belongs to some parametric family $\mathfrak{F} = \{F_\theta \mid \theta \in \Theta\}$. In the case where the unknown parameter $\theta$ needs to be estimated, the distributions of common test statistics such as Cramer-von Mise (CvM), Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS), or Anderson-Darling (AD) will be not distribution-free. The critical values of the relevant statistic must therefore be estimated, say using parametric bootstrap.
Given a sample $X_1,\cdots, X_n \sim F$, the accepted practice would be:

Produce an estimate $\hat{\theta}_n$ based on $X_1,\cdots , X_n$.

Calculate a test statistic using the estimate $\hat{\theta}$. For example, in the case of Anderson-Darling:
$$\hat{A}_n = n\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(F_n(x)-F(x|\hat{\theta}_n))^2}{F(x|\hat{\theta}_n)(1-F(x|\hat{\theta}_n))}\ dF(x|\hat{\theta}_n).$$

Bootstrap to estimate the distribution of $\hat{A}_n$. Repeatedly sample $X^*_{1},\cdots, X^*_{n} \sim F(\cdot|\hat{\theta}_n)$ to produce a sequence of estimates $\hat{\theta}^*_{n}$ and a batch of bootstrapped statistics
$$A^*_{n} = n\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(F_{n}^*(x)-F(x|\hat{\theta}^*_{n}))^2}{F(x|\hat{\theta}^*_{n})(1-F(x|\hat{\theta}^*_{n}))}\ dF(x|\hat{\theta}^*_{n}).$$

From the distribution of the $A^*_n$, estimate the critical value $c^*_\alpha$ for whatever significance level $\alpha$ you're interested in. This can then be used to evaluate the significance of $\hat{A}_n$.


It can be shown, for example in here (see also here for case where $F$ is discrete), that when the test statistic is Cramer-von Mise or Kolmogorov-Smirnov, that the bootstrapped test will behave nicely, i.e.,
$$A^*_{n} - \hat{A}_n \rightarrow 0\ \text{ a.s.},\quad\text{and}\quad \Pr(\hat{A}_n \ge c^*_\alpha) \rightarrow \alpha \tag{*}$$
in the limit of large $n$, under some regularity conditions.
My question is whether this result $(*)$ still holds for the case of the Anderson-Darling statistic? I've looked through a few related references, and the proofs are always given in the context of CvM or KS statistics. In particular, there is a heavy reliance on things like uniform convergence and results like the continuous mapping theorem, which does not seem to apply for the Anderson-Darling statistic (or at least I am unsure how to modify/justify the argument). It seems to me that complications arise due to the denominator term. Is there an easy modification of the existing proofs that apply to Anderson-Darling?
Note: I am aware that, in practice, people do use the Anderson-Darling statistic combined with bootstrap, and that empirically $(*)$ does appear to hold. I am interested in a rigorous proof.
